# How to use wait() and notify() for command processing in thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have Java thread class which purpose is to process commands when they arrive.
My current implementation uses Thread.sleep(50) for checking for new commands, but I want to make it more elegant using wait/notify.
How to do that without introducing bugs ? Here is my code:

```
protected BlockingQueue<Command> currentCmds = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Command>();

@Override
public void run() { 
    while (!dead) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        if (!currentCmds.isEmpty()) {           
            Command cmd = currentCmds.remove();
            processCmd(cmd);
        }
    }
}

public void sendCommand(Command command) {
    currentCmds.add(command);
}
```

I suspect this approach is slowing down my server when many clients are connected.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers under "Related" at right?

Comment: You already have a `BlockingQueue`, why do you use `wait`? You do not need to do any of those things, just use [`BlockingQueue.take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()). Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20907788/2071828), it might be of help. Further, I very much hope `dead` is `volatile`.

Comment: How can I click the up arrow more times @BoristheSpider?

Comment: You wouldn't use wait/notify with any of the concurrent classes. If you want elegance, just use the methods which come with the class itself.

Comment: Thank you @BoristheSpider ! Can you please suggest me some example implementation for my case. As this is core functionality for my server..I don't feel strong enough in multithreading to try it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Java thread class which purpose is to process commands when they arrive.

Basically you want an ExecutorService which is a thread pool and a queue in one.

```
private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void sendRunnable(Runnable run) {
    es.submit(run);
}

public void sendCommand(Command command) {
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           try {
               command.call();
           } catch (Throwable t) {
               t.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   });
}
```

An even simpler solution is to just submit Runnable or Callable and not use Command at all.

Comment: Or let `Command` be a `Runnable`. In any case this is the way to do it. +1